# Click event only firing on the first element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I'm working for my Wordpress project and I created some jQuery code, but it only seems to work on the first element.

**Here is my CSS:**

```
<style type="text/css">
    #hide {
        display:none;
    }
</style>
```

**Here is my jQuery:**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#show").click(function(){
            $("#hide").toggle();
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1) What does your HTML look like? 2) You are using an ID as a selector which will only return one element because ID is *supposed* to be unique.

Answer (score 7):

You probably have multiple ID's with the same name (**#show** and **#hide**) - change all those elements to use a **class** instead (**[ID's are supposed to be unique](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#id-selectors)**), and then you could change your code to something like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".show").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('hide');
        return false;
    });
});
```

and slightly change your CSS as well:

```
.hide {
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: and if there are multiple elements, you probably want to use `$(this)` to look for the closest or next `.hide` element

Comment: @RodrigoAssis #hide is a css style judging from his markup, but yep you're right about $(this) :)

Comment: ok, thank you! one more questions, who knows why when I use shortcode in this code, he is not work... :( <a id="show" href="#">READ MORE</a> <span id="hide">[post-content id=888]</span>